# How to send ALL outbound email of salesforce from the same fix address?

Tags: email, apex-email-service

I have problems with emails sended by salesforce to users and Office 365. The Office 365 admin block all the salesforce automatic email because they are sended from a @company.com address. To prevent fraud I need to send ALL automatic emails from a fixed address, for example salesforce@gmail.com

Comment: [Organization-Wide Email Addresses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=orgwide_email.htm&type=5) should be a candidate to consider.

Comment: What I need exactly is to send email alerts from Salesforce from the office 365 Server and not from a Salesforce Server.